# android use a View from a XML layout to draw a canvas

Tags: android, xml, view, android-canvas

So basically i want to use a xml layout, but i also want a canvas where i can have graphics performed. What i did was make a view in my xml layout as you can see below. Then in my application i made the view draw the canvas, but it is not working. I'm not sure if my method for solving this is completely wrong or what. So please just take a look at my code and tell me if you see a quick fix or if you have a better method. Thanks in advance I really appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />



<View
    android:id="@+id/vMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

that is the xml layout

```
package sm.view.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ViewActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

View v;
Button b;
boolean isRun =true;
SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Thread ourThread;
Canvas canvas;
boolean isTure = true;
TheSurface ourSurfaceView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTest);
    v = (View) findViewById(R.id.vMain);

    canvas = new Canvas();
    ourSurfaceView = new TheSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    v.draw(canvas);
   // v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSurfaceView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
}






public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
public class TheSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    public TheSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder= getHolder();

    }
    public void resume(){
        isRun= true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();  
    }
    public void pause(){
        isRun = false;
        while(true){
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread= null;
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        while(isTure){
        if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;
        //v.draw(canvas);

         canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);
        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        v.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How are you sure it isnt working.  I see a canvas (most likely a white background), and a the paint you are using being set to Color.White.  White on White means not visible!!!

Comment: well the background is automatically black. So showing a white line should show up.

Comment: Why are you creating a SurfaceView then never attaching it to the screen? This feels like all sorts of wrong. Why not just add your SurfaceView subclass to the xml layout?

Comment: Good to know, in the past when I have wanted direct canvas drawing, I have subclassed a UIView object of my own. You might try rather than having generic view that you essentially trying to place your surface view onto, define your custom SurfaceView "as" your view in the XML file. Then implement the onDraw routine within that object.  I have definitely gotten this to work.

Comment: ok so what is the xml code in order to put the SurfaceView subclass to the xml layout? sorry i am new to programming. Thanks for the responses everybody.

Comment: Try what I have setup as an answer!

Comment: i did but it seams to not be working

Answer (score 1):

Start here (and this needs your input as well for the namespace portion "yourProjectNamespace"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >  

    <Button android:id="@+id/bTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />    

    <sm.view.test.TheSurface android:id="@+id/vMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

In your TheSurface

Implement the overideable routines:

```
public TheSurface(Context C){
    super(C);

    // Other setup code you want here
}

public TheSurface(Context C, AttributeSet attribs){
    super(C, attribs);

    // Other setup code you want here
}

public TheSurface(Context C, AttributeSet attribs, int defStyle){
    super(C, attribs, defStyle);

    // Other setup code you want here
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);

    // Other drawing functions here!!!
}
```

This should get your drawing done!!!

Also in my case, you dont have to implement this as a SurfaceView, you could just implement it as a View, and it does not need to implement runnable!!!

Comment: i am getting errors on that. should i be implementing something with that code? i tried overideable routines but i couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Did you put in your namespace where I said to in the answer?

Comment: ya i did sm.view.test
the computer is saying the java code is wrong. it wont even run it.

Comment: Where is it putting the error?  Did you setup the code I put on here as subclass to SurfaceView or simply View?  Did you also change your variable View v; to TheSurface v;?

Comment: sorry for the late responce but i will paste what i have below in a new answer. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but based on the fact that you don't seem to be doing anything with the canvas after you call View.draw() I believe you may be confused. View.draw(Canvas) draws the View onto the Canvas, it doesn't alter the view.

However, if you create the canvas from a bitmap you could then set the bitmap as an ImageView's image:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap( x-size, y-size, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);

Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);

ImageView iView = (ImageView) view;
iView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

However, this is a less correct way than to implement your own View:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MyView)view).mContextVariable = true; //or false, etc
            //you might not need this invalidate, because the click event probably causes and invalidate to be called
            view.invalidate();
        }
    }

    class MyView extends View
    {
        Paint myPaint;
        boolean mContextVariable;

        public MyView(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);

             textPaint = new Paint();
             textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            if(mContextVariable)
            {
                canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);
            }
            else
            {
                //draw something else
            }
            canvas.drawText("testing", 0,0, textPaint);
        }
    }
```

Comment: well basically what I want is a xml layout that has a surface view so i can add a canvas. The canvas will be used to display graphics and such. Like for example a finger paint app where the top 1/4 of the screen is XML buttons to chose a color, and the bottom 3/4 of the screen is a canvas where you can draw stuff. do you kind of understand what I am trying to accomplish now?

Comment: Yes. The View.draw() method is not what you are looking for, though. Instead you want to override the onDraw(canvas) method and make your changes (aka the finger painting) to the canvas it is passed. Then you just redraw your view as often as you like, and it will update with any changes that have been made to the canvas. See my second code block for an example.

Comment: Shouldn't matter that much, have a view and whatever buttons you like or whatever. The view should be your own implementation of view and you can take input onto the canvas however you wish (through touch interaction with the view, perhaps) then redraw the view with the canvas to cause it to update with the changes to the canvas.